# How to get annotations of field in Java

Tags: java, serialization, reflection, annotations, jackson

I have my own Annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Template {
   Class target();
}
```

This Annotation is used in a simple POJO:

```
public class Something {   
    @JsonSerialize(using = TemplateSerializer.class)
    @Template(target = PersonRepresentation.class)
    private TemplateFoo address = new TemplateFoo() {};
}
```

And I have Jackson seriliazer **TemplateSerializer** that gets 'address' passed when serializing the object to JSON.

I wonder how I can get the @Template Annotation given the 'address' instance?
I'd like to gets its 'target' field and then inspect the PersonRepresentation.class

Comment: Annotations are not linked to instances. They're linked to classes and their fields. Your question doesn't make much sense to me. To get this annotation, inspect the `address` field of the `Something` class.

Comment: Hmmm.When using Jackons serialization I have no access to `Something`. But OK. That means I have to change my approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first access the `address` `Field`.

```
Field address = Something.class.getField("address");
Template annotation = address.getAnnotation(Template.class);
```

Then you can get the `target` field of the annotation

```
Class clazz = annotation.target();
```

As JB Nizet has commented, the information provided in an Annotation is relevant to the class, not the the instance.